# Send E-mail and dynamically fill template table with selected values - PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I have a mysql table with unique records, date and email information. I want to automatically send a 'reminder' email to the email address given for each record that the renewal date is coming up. And in case the select condition applies to multiple records and the email address matches, send a list of those records in one email to the matching email address. So the table looks e.g. like this

```
dataID | record_name | accountID | accountName  |   email | renewal_date | notification_period  
1   |   Record1 |   1   |   Client A    |   Aclient@mail.com    |   2016-12-30  |   10      
2   |   Record2 |   2   |   Client B    |   Bclient@mail.com    |   2017-01-25  |   10
3   |   Record3 |   1   |   Client A    |   Aclient@mail.com    |   2016-12-30  |   10
4   |   Record4 |   1   |   Client A    |   Aclient@mail.com    |   2016-01-18  |   14
5   |   Record5 |   3   |   Client C    |   Cclient@mail.com    |   2016-12-30  |   10
6   |   Record6 |   1   |   Client A    |   Aclient@mail.com    |   2016-12-30  |   10
```

I've set up a cronjob (once a day) and I'm using PHPMailer, which both works. How can I now dynamically loop through the table in my template (mail.html) and fill the column with the appropriate information and send it to the desired recepient? Here is what I have so far:

mail.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "database", "password", "table");

$query = "SELECT dataID, record_name, account_name, email, renewal_date, notification_period   
FROM accounts_mail 
WHERE email != ''
AND renewal_date = DATEADD(day,notification_period,CURDATE())";

$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$i=0;
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
$data[$i] = array('dataID'=>$rs['dataID'], 'record_name'=>$rs['record_name'], 'account_name'=>$rs['account_name'], 'email'=> $rs['email'], 'renewal_date'=> $rs['renewal_date'], 'notification_period'=> $rs['notification_period']);
$i++;
}

//echo $data;

require('../PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$time = time();

$message = file_get_contents('mail.html');
$message = str_replace('%currentTime%', $time, $message); 

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SetFrom('mymail@address.com', 'mymail@address.com');
$mail->AddAddress('clientmail@address.com', 'client name');

$mail->Sender = 'mymail@address.com';

$mail->Subject = 'Some Subject';

$mail->MsgHTML($message);

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';


?>
```

mail.thml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Titel & %currentTime%</title>
...
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>

</head>
<body>

<!-- HEADER -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
...
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 15px;" class="padding">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" class="responsive-table">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding: 0;" class="mobile-wrapper">
                                <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">Record Name</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="right">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">Account Name</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is - you seem to be on the right track, so just keep going. Looks like you need to group or sort by the email address to condense messages for each address. Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer for how to do the sending part efficiently.

Comment: This is not really one issue. It looks like multiple issues which you've dumped into one question hence the lack of response. If your really struggling, you need to break this question down and ask at each point you get stuck. So for example, one question could be how you would like to compare multiple strings (email addresses) in an array (if you search Stack this will already be there). Another question might be how to compare two points in time (again..already on stack). You can see where I'm going with this...welcome to the world of programming.